# retrieve year and month from database

Tags: php, mysql

I want to retrieve year and month from my timestamp(eg.'2015-8-02 56:30:00) column like that '2015/5,2015/6,...' to show in row of table.But I cann't it .

**Here is my query**

```
$dateFormat = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
$startDate = '2014-01-23 00:00:00';
$endDate=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat($dateFormat, $startDate);
$year = $date->format('Y/m');
```

Comment: what is the output of `$year`?

Comment: So to be clear: you want the DateTime to be stored as Y/m in the database?

Comment: What you do work right. You have in output "2014/01"

Comment: But - that's not a query...

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in MySQL query, like:

```
SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT( `timestampColumn`,  '%Y/%m' ) as `formattedDate` FROM `yourTable`;
```

Comment: OP wants like this: `2015/5` so make change accordingly

Comment: Right,  DATE_FORMAT( `timestampColumn`,  '%Y/%m' ) then

Comment: make this change in answer